# Derive the asymptotic distribution of maximum likelihood estimator

Tags: convergence-divergence, asymptotics, estimation, parameter-estimation, fisher-information

Suppose that $X_1,...,X_n$ is a random sample from a distribution with pdf :

$$ f(x,\theta)= \frac{\theta^3}{2}x^2e^{-\theta x} \space for \space 0,x,\infty$$

I found that $l(\theta)=-nlog(2)+3nlog(\theta) +2\sum X_i -\theta \sum X_i$

Then $\frac{d^2}{d\theta^2}=\frac{-3n}{\theta^2}$ therefore fisher information $I(\theta)= \frac{3n}{\theta^2}$

**How can i derive the asymptotic distribution from here ?**

Comment: What is your MLE? We have the result $$\sqrt{n}(\hat \theta_{MLE}-\theta)\sim AN\left(0,\frac{1}{E_{\theta}\left[\frac{\partial}{\partial\theta}\ln f_{\theta}(X_1)\right]^2}\right)$$ provided some regularity conditions are met.

Comment: Yes, we have the same. This yields:$$ \hat{\theta}= (0, \frac{\sigma^2}{3n}) $$ if i am not mistaken. However, then our professor states that:$$ \sqrt{3n} \frac{\hat{\theta}-\theta}{\theta} \text{converges in distribution to }N(0,1)$$ and n increases to $\infty$. **How is that**?

Comment: @StubbornAtom, never mind...just noticed the link: According to the theorem of convergence of sample moments for asymptotic distributions.